# How does a body check affect the ruling on Delay of Game penalty call?

Tags: rules, officiating, ice-hockey, nhl

In the NHL (and other leagues and levels I'm sure), a 2 minute minor penalty is assessed when a defender in his own zone clears the puck over the high boards.

This penalty is waived if the clearing attempt goes off an offensive player, or if the puck is deflected off the offensive player's stick.

I am wondering if the penalty would also be waived if, at the same time as the clearing attempt, if the defender were body checked, causing him to lose control of the clear in what might otherwise be a legal clearing attempt.